# Anybody try to use AngularJS and Polymer/paper-dropdown-menu?

Tags: angularjs, polymer, paper-elements

Is there any combination between this:
https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-dropdown-menu
and angularjs.

I tried but still cannot get it to work..

```
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Categories">
            <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
                <core-menu class="menu">
                    <template>
                        <paper-item ng-repeat="c in categories">{{c}}</paper-item>
                    </template>
                </core-menu>
            </paper-dropdown>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: I'm waiting for that in the angular-material project. They said it's included in 0.7 release on Dec 9: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/276

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it using [ng-polymer-elements](https://gabiaxel.github.io/ng-polymer-elements/).

I first created a mapping for the `core-menu`, which will allow you to use ng-model and call methods on your scope when you select an item.

```
    coreMenu: {
       ngModel: {
           primitive: "selected"
       },
       ngTap: {
           event: "core-activate"
       }
    }
```

HTML

```
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="My Items">
        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
            <core-menu class="menu" ng-model="my.item">

                <paper-item ng-repeat="item in items" name="{{item.name}}">
                    {{item.name}}
                </paper-item>

            </core-menu>
        </paper-dropdown>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Notice the `name` attribute in the paper-item. This is very important because it is used by the core-menu to track the selected item. You can use a different attribute name by setting `valueattr="foo"` on the core-menu.

If you need more details or functionality, you can add `ng-tap="myFunction($event)"` to the core-menu element to call a method on your scope. You can then get information about the item selected from the event details.

```
scope.myFunction = function($event) {
  var details = $event.detail.item.attributes.foo.value;
}
```

Comment: Did you get the infinite list component to work by any chance? (with angular binding)

Comment: I didn't know there was one. Do you have an example you can point me to?

Comment: ng-polymer-elements is not compatible with /webcomponents.js, which means, if I am using it, other browsers than chrome will not work correctly. please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: No. That's pretty much the only reason why you WOULD use ng-polymer-elements. To get Angular directives and services to work with webcomponents. Why were you thinking that it wasn't compatible?

Comment: @BlakeBowen - here is the infinite list I was talking about: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-list

Comment: @BlakeBowen: I tried to include both /webcomponents.js and ng-polymer-elements in same page but it wont work even on the sample.

Comment: @Uri - Somehow I missed that the core-list was an infinite list. The core-list is included as part of ng-polymer-elements without any modification, so it should work. However, I haven't tried it out so I'll have to get back to you on that one. Were you able to get my example working?

Comment: @Hung Le - What errors are you getting? Make sure you have the files in the correct order. Getting Polymer to work with Angular can be quite finicky at times because it is always changing. I got this working with version 0.5.1. The paper dropdown element is also difficult to work with because of the web animations it uses, which are always changing. Check out my response to a somewhat similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198932/polymer-paper-dropdown-menu-not-working/27220222#27220222