# Polymer paper-dropdown-menu not working

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

Paper-dropdown-menu component seems to be working fine on the polymer website [ https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-dropdown-menu/demo.html ].

However, I downloaded polymer/web components 0.5.1 and the menu doesn't seem to render at all [on any browser].
[ http://idineth.com/garage-website/bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/demo.html ]

Any idea why this is the case? Polymer website seems to be using the same branch if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: what method did you use for installation? this type of behavior happens when components or imports are missing.

Comment: installed using bower..

Comment: as of today i am having the same issue on what was a working app.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these imports.

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/web-animations-next/web-animations.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/web-animations-js/web-animations.html">
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick.. 
However, web-animations-js didn't get pulled in when using bower to install webcompoentns or core/paper elements.
Also, the default color and the background-color of the paper-dropdown-menu are set to white/transparent resulting in not showing it up.

Comment: For Polymer 1.0 you will need to import the paper-listbox <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">